# How to desgin database for smart catalog application

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, diagram, erd

I'm currently working on my final year project, the project is to create an web app to help disability people to be able to access to current technology.

The app will basically work as smart catalog where user create their profile, they can select many area that they are identified with. The area can be Hearing issue, Vision or Speech and Wheelchair.

Once they selected the areas, list of function that available will be display to them they can choose whether function they like or dont like. if they dont like they can ignore it.

After they selecting function, all of application that relate to selected function will display.

I have design the ER diagram and want someone who good at ER to look and help me to fix it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't Know why you added the area and functions columns in user table, because we are saving them in user area and user functions table.I have made rough db diagram take a look, hope it will clear your view. if you have any doubt just ask
This db diagram made by keeping in mind that user can select multiple areas and Functions

[image: Db Diagram]